# matlab with classes - save struct in empty double array

Tags: matlab, struct, properties

I try to create a class in matlab

It has a property `children`

```
properties
    children
```

If this variable is written to - it is supposed to be an arrays of structs
it fails with

```
    function obj = Init(obj, valueList)
        %INIT Initialise with vector of new parameter sets
        newSet = obj.ParamSet;
        newSet.values = valueList;
        obj.children(end + 1) = newSet; % <<< error
```

Error is :

> Conversion to double from struct is not possible.

This is the struct that is used

```
methods(Static)
    function paramset = ParamSet()
        newset.('values') = [];
        newset.('fitness') = 0;
        paramset = newset;
    end
end
```

Comment: You cannot store structs in a double array. You can store them in cells, or make a struct of structs however.

Comment: When you say "an array of structs", do you mean an N*1 struct with consistent fields, or an array of arbitrary structs? The former means `obj.children` will be a structure array, the latter means you need a cell array... Please provide a [MCVE] where you create an example of what `children` should be - this may not require the whole class definition

Comment: I posted an answer without knowing the class of `ParamSet`. Can you please update your post, with the class of `obj.ParamSet`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The simple solution is to assign if it’s empty:

```matlab
if isempty(obj.children)
   obj.children = newSet;
else
   obj.children(end + 1) = newSet;
end
```